# Git says master is up to date but its not

Tags: git, repository, branch

I have a repo in which I had pushed changes to the master branch,then I created other branch (4taFase) and started doing some pushes there. After I finished my work I wanted to push to MASTER, so I checked-out to master, but it says its up to date when it clearly is not ( I did git add, commit and push). **I have already tried git pull, git merge and everthing I read on the internet**. Please help and thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by `I wanted to push to MASTER`?  Do you want to _merge_ your branch into master?

Comment: Running `git pull origin master` from your local `master` branch should have synched up and fixed the problem.  What exactly happened after you pulled?

Comment: If Git says it is up to date, it is in fact up to date. The questions are: up to date with *what* and *what do you want it to be up to date with instead* and answering these questions requires more information than you have given us here...

Answer (score 1):

From your description I see that you currently have 2 branches:

1. master
2. 4taFase

4taFase is based on master but has several commits that master doesn't have. If so you have following options:

1. Do [merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) from 4taFase to master. You'll have all work you done in 4taFase copied to master but in single commit.

   `git checkout master
    git merge 4taFase`
2. Do [cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) to transfer particular commit(s) from 4taFase to master

   `git checkout master
   git cherry-pick <commit-hash from 4taFase>`